# How to concat multiple dataframe without without typing every single dataframe name

Tags: python-3.x

I want to concat many DataFrame together without listing all of the name in the concat function. The list of name of dataframe I already got in the form of a list of string elements. Is there anyway I can pass it into the concat function?

```
df_1 = pandas.read_csv('some_file_1')
df_2 = pandas.read_csv('some_file_2')
df_3 = pandas.read_csv('some_file_3')

some_list = ['df_1','df_2','df_3']

pandas.concat(some_list)
```

Comment: `list` is a reserved word, don't name your variables `list`

Comment: I just want illustrate what I attempted to do. Question edited anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

to_concat = [ "df1", "df2", "df3" ]

df = pd.concat(map(lambda z: eval(z),to_concat))

print(df)
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer then? (would prevent the question show up as unanswered, among other things). Also maybe read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers